Error E:Malformed entry 1 in list file/etc/apt/sources.list
question edited as request Apparently software is unsupported.
E:Malformed entry 1 in list file/etc/apt/sources.list d/archive_uri_http_archive_ubuntu_com_realter_noble.list. List could not be read. Havent a clue after exhaustive search. Any help greatly appreciated thanks Graham b

Please post the output of the command cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Please [edit] your question to clarify the file name - is it /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri_http_archive_ubuntu_com_realter_noble.list - or something else? See also How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?

Edit the question and post the output

This question is similar to: How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. For this problem you will also need to read the question (not the answer) to How do I remove a malformed line from my ubuntu.sources?.

@steeldriver This clarity issue that effects users of Ubuntu 24.04 and later has been vexing me, so I posted a new question about this same E:Malformed entry 1 in list file/etc/apt/sources.list error message in Ubuntu 24.04 systems. I am looking for an updated answer to this question that I posted that is specific to Ubuntu 24.04 and later.
